# How to change the background color for a PHPPresentation Slide?

Tags: php, background-color, phppresentation

I've recently started to work with the PHPPresentation library to create Powerpoint presentations. I need to change the background color of certain slides, I looked over the code samples that they offer and inside the developer documentation, they both lack this vital information.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/tree/develop/samples 
http://phppresentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slides.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the repository from github and searched for '*background*'. There were quite a few results, both in samples and the source code.

One example is [*Sample 15*](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/samples/Sample_15_Background.php). Below is an excerpt from lines [14](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/samples/Sample_15_Background.php#L14)-[23](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/samples/Sample_15_Background.php#L23):

```
// Create slide
echo date('H:i:s') . ' Create slide'.EOL;
$oSlide1 = $objPHPPresentation->getActiveSlide();
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeDrawing);
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeRichText);
// Slide > Background > Color
$oBkgColor = new Color();
$oBkgColor->setColor(new StyleColor(StyleColor::COLOR_DARKGREEN));
$oSlide1->setBackground($oBkgColor);
```

It appears that method `setBackground()` is defined in [AbstractSlide.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/src/PhpPresentation/Slide/AbstractSlide.php) at line [349](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/src/PhpPresentation/Slide/AbstractSlide.php#L349) as of revision [d07784c](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/commit/d07784c877c2557a04389c04e72e74678e7bc667).

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting this functionality to appear inside the slide samples, I did found out how to achieve it by searching inside their API documentation and tracking down every used class and method. The difficult thing was to convert the colors that I was using from RGB to ARGB.

Comment: Yeah it is a shame it isn't mentioned in the documentation. Perhaps somebody should request it be added.

Comment: i wrote this $currentSlide = $objPhpPresentation->createSlide();
            $oBkgColor = new Color();
            $oBkgColor->setColor(new StyleColor(StyleColor::COLOR_DARKGREEN));
            $currentSlide->setBackground($oBkgColor); and i get this error "Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color::setColor()"

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: it's disabled for me that's why !!

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments. [Ask a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and mention this post as related.

Comment: "You have reached your question limit"

Comment: If you haven't already read it, check out [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/341145)